# SQL Server 2012 - Transparent Data Encryption not available in this edition

Tags: encryption, sql-server-2012

Let me start by saying that the instance of SQL Server 2012 I am attempting to set up TDE (Transparent Data Encryption) on, is the Enterprise edition.

However, when following [the MSDN tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc278098%28v=sql.100%29.aspx#_Toc189384676) tutorial, I get to the following line:

```
create database encryption key with algorithm = AES_256 encryption by server certificate TDECertificate
```

and I get the error:

```
Msg 33117, Level 16, State 1, Line 6
Transparent Data Encryption is not available in the edition of this SQL Server instance. See books online for more details on feature support in different SQL Server editions.
```

Can anybody advise me as to why I would be getting this error?

Comment: What's the output of running `SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('productversion'), SERVERPROPERTY ('productlevel'), SERVERPROPERTY ('edition')` on your instance?

Comment: +1 because that query would have lead me to see that I was in error. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: Good to hear. I'll put that as an answer if you wouldn't mind accepting it :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've tried the same on my 2012 Developer instance and had no problems.

Ensure that the instance you're connected to is indeed Enterprise or Developer edition by running

`SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('productversion'), SERVERPROPERTY ('productlevel'), SERVERPROPERTY ('edition')`

Answer (score 2):

Found the problem. It was between the chair and the keyboard.

We have two instances of SQL Server installed and I was querying the wrong one.